# MVC 5 C# params array string

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create multiple roles for users.  There is a common role for all which is Basic and an additional role of choice. I get the second role based on an integer value selected from a signup form.  I then use a switch to match the value to the role name.
Below is what I tried but I get an error "Index was outside the bounds of the array".

`string[] mt = new string[1];`

```
                switch (n)
                {
                    case 1:
                        mt[0] = "Basic";
                        mt[1] = "Reader";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        mt[0] = "Basic";
                        mt[1] = "Blogger";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        mt[0] = "Basic";
                        mt[1] = "Editor";
                        break;
                    default:
                        mt[0] = "Basic";
                        break;
                }


 if (mt!= null)
                    {
                        result = await UserManager.AddToRolesAsync(user.Id, mt);
                    }
```

I don't really know if I am doing this the right way. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: your code is trying to access the first and second items from your array. But what is the length of your array ? Looks like it is only 1. That is the reason you are getting that error. Your array has only one item and you are trying to access the second item!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array can only hold one value, because it has a length of 1. Increase its size to 2 using `string[] mt = new string[2];`

Then you can reduce some duplication, since you always assign "Basic" and then get rid of the redundant null check:

```
string[] mt = new string[2] {"Basic", null};
switch (n)
{
    case 1:
        mt[1] = "Reader";
        break;
    case 2:
        mt[1] = "Blogger";
        break;
    case 3:
        mt[1] = "Editor";
        break;
    default: break;
}

result = await UserManager.AddToRolesAsync(user.Id, mt);
```

**HOWEVER:** I would suggest a different clearer approach:

```
//create a dictionary with all roles
var roleDic = new Dictionary<int, string> {
     {1, "Reader"},
     {2, "Blogger"},
     {3, "Editor"},
};

//get the role that matches your n variable
var newRole = roleDic.FirstOrDefault (d => d.Key == n).Value;
//create the array for the UserManager
var roles = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(newRole) ? new [] {"Basic", newRole} : new[] {"Basic"};

result = await UserManager.AddToRolesAsync(user.Id, roles);
```

If you ever want to add more than one role per user and n becomes a collection of `int` values, this becomes:

```
var roleDic = new Dictionary<int, string> {
     {1, "Reader"},
     {2, "Blogger"},
     {3, "Editor"},
     {4, "SuperUser"},
     {5, "Administrator"},
     {6, "BackupAdmin"}
};

var rolestoAdd = new List<int> { 2, 4};

var newRoles = roleDic.Where(x => rolestoAdd.Contains(x.Key))
                     .Select (x => x.Value);
var roles = new List<string> {"Basic"};

roles.AddRange(newRoles);
result = await UserManager.AddToRolesAsync(user.Id, roles.ToArray());
```

This way you save yourself a clumsy switch statement which might grow over a couple of pages, once you hit some 20ish roles. Additionally you've seperated your role definition from your logic and (imho) it is more readable. (Others might find a gigantic switch or if-else block more concise, that is up to you.)

Answer (score 0):

Change `string[] mt = new string[1];`
to `string[] mt = new string[2];`
The numer between [] stands for the amount of items in your array

You were probably thinking of max index

Comment: Thanks being the first to help

Answer (score 0):

If length of array is variable, you probably should use `List<string>` instead:

```
// Initialize list of roles and "Basic" beforehand
// as it should be added at any case.
List<string> mt = new List<string> { "Basic" };
// Add additional roles as needed
switch (n)
{
    case 1:
        mt.Add("Reader");
        break;
    case 2:
        mt.Add("Blogger");
        break;
    case 3:
        mt.Add("Editor");
        break;
}


if (mt!= null)
{
    result = await UserManager.AddToRolesAsync(user.Id, mt.ToArray());
}
```